# featherlight ajax post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, featherlight.js

How can I load a Featherlight modal with ajax content by sending POST data in the featherlight request instead of GET?

```
$.featherlight({
    ajax: 'some.php'
});
```

The above code will load the content from 'some.php'. What if I want to send along a POST value?

For example with jQuery I would use:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
```

That would pass along some POST data. This is what I'm trying to accomplish with featherlight.js. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Old question but, in case someone falls here:

As Johnny suggests and, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight), Featherlight does not provide any built in functionality for AJAX POST.

You can, however, make your POST request and call featherlight with the response:

```
$.post(myUrl, myData, function (response) {
    $.featherlight(response, configuration);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the `featherlight.js` file, the method called for the ajax call is `load` which is like `$.get`, `load` can take data, but it was not added in featherlight code as you can see below.

```
ajax: {
    ...
    var $container = $('<div></div>').load(url, function(response, status){
    ...
},
```

So, to answer your question, you cannot send post data.